# What is the symbology of this pin?

Tags: communism, weapons, soviet-union, flag, symbols

I found this recently among old belongings and can't remember when or where I received it. Very curious about its source but more importantly its symbology. Sorry if this is the wrong place, there's no symbology stackexchange.

[image: Pin with red field, hammer and sickle, fortified wall, cannon, and key shaped door]

Comment: I would try asking this question over at the history stackexchange they would probably be able to give you some info

Comment: @JMERICKS might be right, but I'd say this question is definitely on-topic here: https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4729/19301

Comment: This is almost certainly an enameled pin created for one of the anniversaries of the Russian Revolution. It's not a city coat-of arms (of which there are many, but which usually include the city name), and it's a bit too generic for  a military insignia or medal. However, it seems the Soviets absolutely ***loved*** badges of this sort, and pumped out thousands. I don't know enough about it to identify the particulars. But maybe that will help focus your search...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[A reverse image search on the Russian search engine Yandex](https://yandex.com/images/search?source=collections&rpt=imageview&url=https%3A%2F%2Favatars.mds.yandex.net%2Fget-images-cbir%2F4537934%2FnqSH1x8ZzTU7T9HxRQbxTQ4960%2Forig&cbir_id=4537934%2FnqSH1x8ZzTU7T9HxRQbxTQ4960) shows many other pictures of that badge, mostly in auctions.

Most of the pages aren't descriptive or link to auction pages with many other badges where it's hard to find this particular badge. [This page on meshok.ru.com](https://meshok.ru.com/item/142744880_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BC_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%90%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB_%D0%9A%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%A0_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%A3%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%A0) (seemingly an auction site for collectibles) lists a lot with a picture of the same badge as the one in your picture, it does have a more descriptive title:

> Памятник рабочим завода Арсенал (Киев) знак значок СССР Украина УССР

According to Google Translate, that means:

> Monument to the workers of the Arsenal plant (Kiev) sign icon USSR Ukraine Ukrainian SSR

[Another lot on that site](https://meshok.net/item/223715724_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BC_%D0%9A%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2_%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%90%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%9A_041_%D0%90/basket), also with your badge, has the following description:

> Памятник арсенальцам Киев Пушка Артиллерия (К-041-А)

According to Google Translate, that means:

> Monument to the Arsenals Kiev Cannon Artillery (K-041-A)

The cannon depicted seems to be this one:

[image]

<sub>Image taken from [dsnews.ua](https://www.dsnews.ua/ukr/nasha_revolyutsiya_1917/-tridyuymovki-i-garmati-z-midnimi-stvolami-chim-voyuvala-09102019200000)</sub>

According to the accompanying article by [dsnews.ua](https://www.dsnews.ua/ukr/nasha_revolyutsiya_1917/-tridyuymovki-i-garmati-z-midnimi-stvolami-chim-voyuvala-09102019200000) (in Ukrainian):

> Ще одним цікавим взірцем артилерійського озброєння доби Перших визвольних змагань була 76,2-мм гірська гармата зразка 1909-го — варіант французької системи Данґліза-Шнейдера, який виготовлявся в Росії за ліцензією. Випускали ці гармати Путіловський і Петроградський гарматний заводи, а лафети до них постачав Київський арсенал. Гармата була досить компактною (важила в бойовому положенні 625 кг), з коротшим стволом, ніж у польової тридюймовки. До того ж, вона могла розбиратись на сім частин для транспортування вʼючним способом.

Which according to Google Translate means:

> Another interesting example of the artillery armament of the First Liberation War was the 76.2-mm mountain gun of the 1909 model, a variant of the French Danglis-Schneider system, which was manufactured in Russia under license. These guns were produced by the Putilovsky and Petrograd cannon factories, and gun carriages were supplied to them by the Kiev arsenal. The gun was quite compact (weighed in combat position 625 kg), with a shorter barrel than the field three-inch. In addition, it could be disassembled into seven parts for transportation by packing.

---

In conclusion, I think it's safe to say that the cannon depicted on your badge refers to the ones manufactured in a part of the USSR that's now Ukraine.